# sqlalchemy date as string in raw sql

Tags: python, date, sqlalchemy

Consider the following table:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "t_employee"

    id = Column(Integer(20), Sequence('%s_id_seq' % __tablename__), primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(30))
    last_name = Column(String(30))
    email = Column(String(50))
    start_date = Column(Date, default=datetime.now)
    end_date = Column(Date)
```

How do I select using strings instead of dates in a raw sql in sqlalchemy? The following works in mysql but not in Oracle:

```
session.query(Employee).\
    filter("end_date IS NULL OR end_date>='%s'" % datetime.now()).all()
```

The best scenario would be if I could use either string or date (interchangeably) whenever dealing with Date or DateTime columns (I have tried TypeDecorator to no avail)

Please notice that the question refers to **raw** sql (I know this can be done using predicates) ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't interpolate values into SQL using string formatting. In the case of a `datetime` object, the default string format happens to work for MySQL, but that is just serendipity and luck.

In this case, don't use raw SQL and have SQLAlchemy translate the datetime object to something the backend database understands for you:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_

session.query(Employee).filter(
    or_(Employee.end_date == None, Employee.end_date >= datetime.now())
).all()
```

Even when using raw SQL, I'd have sqlalchemy generate that SQL and use bind parameters:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam, column
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime
from sqlalchemy import or_

dtnow = bindparam('dtnow', datetime.now(), DateTime)
end_date = column('enddate', DateTime)

session.query(Employee).\
    filter(or_(end_date == None, end_date >= dtnow)).all()
```

That filter expression is turned into properly escaped SQL for your database backend, whatever backend that may be. When no backend is set, the expression becomes:

```
>>> str(or_(end_date == None, end_date >= dtnow))
'enddate IS NULL OR enddate >= :dtnow'
```

and the `datetime.now()` value will be passed in as a SQL parameter to the backend database cursor when executing.

A last resort is to use the [`text()` type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam, text

dtnow = bindparam('dtnow', datetime.now(), DateTime)
session.query(Employee).\
    filter(text('end_date is NULL or end_date >= :dtnow', bindparams=[dtnow])).all()
```

I'd otherwise avoid mixing raw SQL and the SQLAlchemy ORM altogether. Use raw SQL directly with the database connection only:

```
conn = session.connection()
conn.execute(text('SELECT * FROM t_employee WHERE end_date IS NULL OR end_date>=:dtnow'),
   dtnow=datetime.now())
```

Comment: As I said, I know this can be done using predicates, and I also know that this is the best way but my question was about raw SQL

Comment: @Ofir: Don't mix raw SQL and declarative statements then. If you need to use raw SQL, use the connection `.execute()` method and use SQL parameters instead.

Comment: Can you give an example? 10x.

Comment: Thank you Martijn. It's worth noting that there is also a useful [text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) function to do this.