# Dates as strings when submitting raw SQL with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, when I submit a raw SQL query that selects a datetime attribute, the date is returned as a string. However, when I use the `Table.select` method instead of raw SQL, the date is properly formatted as a `datetime.datetime` object.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

eng = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
meta = sa.MetaData()
foos = sa.Table('foos', meta,
                sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
                sa.Column('created_at', sa.DateTime))
meta.create_all(eng)
conn = eng.connect()
```

Now, when we query using the object-oriented appraoch:

```
>>> dict(conn.execute(foos.select()).fetchone())
{'id': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 11, 0)}
```

That's a `datetime.datetime`. Whereas, using raw SQL:

```
>>> dict(conn.execute('select * from foos').fetchone())
{'id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-06-01 11:00:00.000000'}
```

That's a string. (Although the integer attribute `id` is recognized as such!)

I know I can use `datetime.strptime` to parse the string but my questions are

- Why do I get a string?
- Can I get sqlalchemy to give me a datetime instead, using raw SQL? And if so, how?

NB: I am aware of [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477817/sqlalchemy-date-as-string-in-raw-sql) but it doesn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `SQLite` as `DB`, the date and time types are stored as `strings`, when you use `raw SQL`, the query result will be in string format, however, when you use `sqlalchemy`, date and time types are stored as strings which are then converted back to `datetime` objects when rows are returned. Refer to official doc about [sqlalchemy.types.DateTime](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime).

Comment: So the answer to my second question would be to use any other database than `SQLite`? Quoting the official doc: "Most DBAPIs have built in support for the datetime module, with the noted exception of SQLite"

Comment: You can provide information about result columns manually in SQLAlchemy when using textual SQL: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#specifying-result-column-behaviors